# Can't assign returned java.util.ArrayList to scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer. Why?

Tags: java, scala, collections, scala-java-interop

I've imported this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val size: Int = blubb.getSize
var fields: ArrayBuffer[Field] = new ArrayBuffer[Field]

size match
{
    case 1 => fields.append(field)
    case 2 => fields = field.getNeighbours)
}
```

now getNeighbours returns a java.util.ArrayList instead of an ArrayBuffer (it's a Java class I have no control over).

Compiler says

> Expression of type ArrayList[Field] doesn't conform to expected type
>   ArrayBuffer[Field]

Shouldn't JavaConversions take care of that? How can I convert the ArrayList to an ArrayBuffer easily? (I do NOT want to replace the ArrayBuffer with an ArrayList in the Scala code!)

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$ should show what's supported.

Comment: I would mention that it's generally preferable to use the `JavaConverters` rather than `JavaConversions` so that you know (because you explicitly specify) what's going to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `ArrayBuffer` is a particular implementation of a `Buffer`, backed by an `Array`. You cannot have an `ArrayBuffer` backed by an `ArrayList`.

`JavaConversions` offers you a wrapping conversion from `java.util.List` to `Buffer` (not `ArrayBuffer`).

Either you retype your `fields` variable as a `Buffer[Field]`, or you have to *copy* the elements of the `ArrayList` to a new `ArrayBuffer`:

```
fields = ArrayBuffer(field.getNeighours: _*)
```

Comment: Your second example won't compile for me:       case 2 => {fields = ArrayBuffer(field.getNeighbours(new Vector2(this.posX, this.posY), world): _*); fields.append(field); fieldsCount = 3} Expected Seq[NotInferedA] actual ArrayList[Field]

Comment: Actually your first doesn't work either. 

    Expression of type ArrayList[Field] doesn't conform to expected type Buffer[Field]

Comment: You're right. Had to reload not only my idea, but also my whole system. Not sure why. Didn't do any updates today (rolling release, Archlinux) oO Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because an ArrayBuffer is not an ArrayList. sjrd suggests using javas built in conversion, but you could also just use a for loop to copy the data from the arraylist to a new ArrayBuffer before passing it.